Superpose two spatially separated single-photons into the same spatically mode
Consider two single photons, and let the states of them be $|H,A; V,B\rangle$. Here, $|H, A; V,B\rangle$ means that a horizontally-polarized single photon state is highly localized in spatial mode $A$ and a vertically-polarized single photon state is highly localized in spatial mode $B$. Similarly, we can consider another state $|H,B; V,A\rangle$, which is orthogonal to $|H,A; V,B\rangle$.
Now, first consider $|H,A; V,B\rangle$. I bring only a photon in mode $B$ to mode $A$, and I expect that we have two photons in mode $A$, which I express as $|H, V, A\rangle$. Next, consider $|H,B; V,A\rangle$, and do the same thing. As before, the final state seems to be $|H, V, A\rangle$ because considering the symmetry of boson, i.e., it must be symmetric under particle exchange, this state is only one possibility. However, this operation does not preserve the inner product between $|H,A; V,B\rangle$ and $|H,B; V,A\rangle$, i.e., the operation is prohibited by quantum mechanics, because the inner product of these states before the operation is $0$ while the one of the final state is 1.
Can anyone point out where I made a mistake? Or, is it that I should have introduced another degree of freedom, such as orbital, to make the two final states orthogonal? If so, dose it mean that we cannot superpose two photons without changing its temporal freedom?

Sorry that "orbital" should be some local wave-function.

What do you mean by "bring a photon in mode B to mode A" and vice versa? This seems to be the crux of the matter. If you mean that you apply some unitary transformation to the initial state to get the final state (for instance via some unitary time evolution), then it is impossible to "bring" your states $|H,B;V,A\rangle$ and $|H,A;V,B\rangle$ to the same final state $|H,V,A\rangle$, since unitary transformations are invertible. Thus, either there needs to be some other quantum number that distinguishes the final states that you are ignoring, or you just can't do what you're trying to do.

Thank you for your comment. By "bring a photon in mode B to mode A", I meant Bob sends his photon to Alice where mode A and mode B are spatial mode in Alice's lab and Bob's lab, respectively. As you suggested, I need some other quantum number. The time evolution: $|H,B; V,A; \phi_1\rangle \rightarrow |H,V,A;\phi_1\rangle$ and $|H,A; V,B; \phi_1\rangle \rightarrow |H,V,A;\phi_2\rangle$ is OK, where $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$, are some orthogonal states of the extra quantum number. Is this correct? What's an example of other quantum number for a photon, other than polarization and position?

In short: In placing a photon from mode $A$ to mode $B$, there is no real "exchange". For an exchange you would also need to bring the other photon from $B$ to $A$. Then, the initial and final state are indeed the same. The inner product $\langle H,A;V,B|H,B;V,A\rangle$ is indeed zero, because the two particles are distinguishable (so replacing $H$ by $V$ in mode $A$ and the vice versa in mode $B$ does not reflect this bosonic symmetry). I hope this answers your question.
Some suggestions and extra info:
If you would like to perform some calculations or tests, I would advice you to reformulate your states. For example: photons can have $H$ and $V$ polarizations, and they can be in spatial modes $A$ and $B$. Then a general state can be described as
$$|\alpha\rangle_{H,A}\otimes|\beta\rangle_{H,B}\otimes|\gamma\rangle_{V,A}\otimes|\delta\rangle_{V,B}\,,$$
where $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ and $\delta$ represent the numbers of photons in the modes $(H,A)$, $(H,B)$, etc. Then the states you mentioned earlier would be described as:
\begin{align*}
|H,A;V,B\rangle &= |1\rangle_{H,A}\otimes|0\rangle_{H,B}\otimes|0\rangle_{V,A}\otimes|1\rangle_{V,B}\,, \\[0.2cm]
|H,B;V,A\rangle &= |0\rangle_{H,A}\otimes|1\rangle_{H,B}\otimes|1\rangle_{V,A}\otimes|0\rangle_{V,B}\,, \\[0.2cm]
|H,V,A\rangle &= |1\rangle_{H,A}\otimes|0\rangle_{H,B}\otimes|1\rangle_{V,A}\otimes|0\rangle_{V,B}\,.
\end{align*}
For performing calculations, it is very useful to then also define annihilation and creation operators for each mode. Note that if either $0$ or $1$ photon can occupy each mode, then your system is fermionic.

Thank you for your comment. I didn't mean "exchange" but I meant, for instance, Bob sends his photon to Alice where mode A and mode B are spatial mode in Alice's lab and Bob's lab, respectively. This is always possible, isn't it? I learn from the above discussion, and I wrote a reply, and does it make sense to you? Also, as I asked in the thread, do you know some example of quantum numbers for a photon, other than polarization and position?
